# Proper Usage of Update and FixedUpdate Movements With Animations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Been doing a lot of reading and I have somewhat of an idea but not 100% sure about the proper way to handle a GameObject's movement along with its Animations.  In this case it is my player movement scripts.

So what I was wondering is should I be placing the logic of my "movement" variable in my Update or FixedUpdate and should I also change anything up with my animation placement being in Update or put it in FixedUpdate?  I have tried both and I see similar results, but I just want to have good practice for when bigger projects come along.

```
void Update(){
    // IF we are allowed to move.
    if(_PMS.canMove){
        // Get a -1, 0 or 1.
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        // Get Vector2 direction.
        movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * _PMS.invertXDirection, moveVertical * _PMS.invertYDirection);
        // Apply direction with speed.
        movement *= speed;
        // IF the user has an animation set.
        if(anim != null){
            // Play animations.
            Helper_Manager.PlayerAnimation(moveHorizontal, moveVertical, anim, _PMS);
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    // IF we are allowed to move.
    if(_PMS.canMove){
        // Apply the force for movement.
        rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation should be triggered along with the physical movement. I would move all the movement calculations to FixedUpdate() and just get the input in Update(). This way, all the movement and animation are triggered together.

```
void Update() {

    // IF we are allowed to move.
    if(_PMS.canMove){
        // Get a -1, 0 or 1.
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
    }
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    // IF we are allowed to move.
    if(_PMS.canMove){
        // Get Vector2 direction.
        movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * _PMS.invertXDirection, moveVertical * _PMS.invertYDirection);
        // Apply direction with speed.
        movement *= speed;
        // IF the user has an animation set.
        if(anim != null){
            // Play animations.
            Helper_Manager.PlayerAnimation(moveHorizontal, moveVertical, anim, _PMS); // always call this, assuming you play an idle animation if moveHorizontal and moveVertical are 0
        }

        // Apply the force for movement.
        rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
}
```